# Chrome ver 65 iframe bug ? or Tableau bug?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, tableau-api

pls see this by Chrome ver 65.

## html

```
<!-- div display: block. NOT corrupted -->
<div id="block">
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/Whereyoucanrentviz-Mobile-Radiobutton/Whereyoucanrentcheaperwith10km?%3Aembed=y&%3AshowVizHome=no" width="1200" height="500">
</iframe>
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('none_to_block').style.display = 'block';" value="block!" />

<!-- div display: none - click block! button - to block. !!! corrupted !!! -->
<div id="none_to_block">
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/Whereyoucanrentviz-Mobile-Radiobutton/Whereyoucanrentcheaperwith10km?%3Aembed=y&%3AshowVizHome=no" width="1200" height="500">
</iframe>
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('hidden_to_visible').style.visibility = 'visible';" value="visible!" />

<!-- div visibility: hidden - click visible! button - to visible. !!! NOT corrupted !!! -->
<div id="hidden_to_visible">
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/Whereyoucanrentviz-Mobile-Radiobutton/Whereyoucanrentcheaperwith10km?%3Aembed=y&%3AshowVizHome=no" width="1200" height="500">
</iframe>
</div>
```

## css

```
#none_to_block {
  display: none;
}
#hidden_to_visible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waqzxdav/)

1. First div is OK
2. Second div is NG
3. Third div is OK

cf. ALL OK by Chrome ver 64.

Chrome ver 65 iframe bug ? or Tableau bug ?

Comment: upload screenshot what problems and what result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great analysis of the problem! 
Apart from chrome v65, This is also happening on Internet Explorer. @hyukawa your jsfiddle is able to recreate the problem in IE v11 too.

I am dealing with the same issue.
I have several iframes with embedded tableau viz (Tableau server v10.4) on my web page.
I use the same display:none/block mechanism to hide/show the charts on my page.

As a temporary workaround, I am calling the `viz.setFrameSize(width,height)` every time I toggle the display(none/block), seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with visibility:hidden is, it occupies white space for the viz. 
and problem with display:block is, it is not rendering the viz completely.

I played a little bit with the jsfiddle provided by hyukawa. 
So, in visibility:hidden option, added some css (position: absolute;  top: 0;  left: 0;) to viz parent. and it worked.

Here is the [link for jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sasawant1977/x4sLbfy5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="viz-container">
  <!-- div display: block. NOT corrupted -->
  <div id="first" class="tableau-viz">
    <iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/Whereyoucanrentviz-Mobile-Radiobutton/Whereyoucanrentcheaperwith10km?%3Aembed=y&%3AshowVizHome=no" width="1200" height="500">
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <!-- div visibility: hidden - click visible! button - to visible. !!! NOT corrupted !!! -->
  <div id="second" style="visibility:hidden;" class="tableau-viz">
    <iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/180315_class-culture_dotplots/lit-authors?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no&:host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F&:embed_code_version=3&:tabs=no&:toolbar=yes&:animate_transition=yes&:display_static_image=no&:display_spinner=no&:display_overlay=yes&:display_count=yes&:loadOrderID=0" width="1200" height="500">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.viz-container {
  position:fixed;  
}

.tableau-viz{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var displayedViz = "first";

$(document).ready(function(){
    function toggleViz(){
    $(".tableau-viz").css("visibility", "hidden");
    if(displayedViz == "first") {
      $("#second").css("visibility", "visible");
      displayedViz = "second";
    } else {
      $("#first").css("visibility", "visible");
      displayedViz = "first";
    }
    console.log('displayed : ' + displayedViz);
  }

  $("#toggleBtn").on('click', function() {
    toggleViz()
  });
});
```